# python interpolation of some datapoints in dataset / merging lists

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

In an .xlsx file there is logged machine data in a way that is not suitable for further calculations. Meaning I've got a file that contains depth data of a cutting tool. Each depth increment comes with several further informations like pressure, rotational speed, forces and many more.

As you can see in [some datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prLZn.png) the resolution of the depth parameter (0.01) is insufficient, as other parameters are updated more often. So I want to interpolate between two consecutive depth datapoints.

[What is important to know, this effect doesn't occure on each depth. When the cutting tool moves fast, everything is fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FhDz.png)

[Here is also an example file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0MWqVazAnA3vXFQAGceIYfbyxazoaiU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104745763327967732762&rtpof=true&sd=true)

So I just need to interpolate values of the depth, when the differnce between two consecutive depth datapoints is 0.01

I've tried the following approach:

1. Open as dataframe, rename, drop NaN, convert to list
2. count identical depths in list and transfer them to dataframe
3. calculate Delta between depth i and depth i-1 (i.e. to the predecessor), replace NaN with "0"
4. Divide delta depth by number of time steps if 0.009 < delta depth < 0.011 -->interpolated depth
5. empty List of Lists with the number of elements of the sublist corresponding to the duration
6. Pass values from interpolated depth to the respective sublists --> List 1
7. Transfer elements from delta_depth to sublists --> Liste 2
8. Merge List 1 and List 2
9. Flatten the Lists
10. replace the original depth value by the interpolated values in dataframe

It looks like this, but at point 8 (merging) I don't get what I need:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import zip_longest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#open and rename of some columns 
df_raw=pd.read_excel(open('---.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='---')  
df_raw=df_raw.rename(columns={"---"})

#drop NaN 
df_1=df_raw.dropna(subset=['depth'])

#convert to list
li = df_1['depth'].tolist()

#count identical depths in list and transfer them to dataframe
df_count = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[i, len([*group])] for i, group in groupby(li)])
df_count = df_count.rename(columns={0: "depth", 1: "duration"})

#calculate Delta between depth i and depth i-1 (i.e. to the predecessor), replace NaN with "0".
df_count["delta_depth"] = df_count["depth"].diff()
df_count=df_count.fillna(0)

#Divide delta depth by number of time steps if 0.009 < delta depth < 0.011
df_count["inter_depth"] = np.where(np.logical_and(df_count['delta_depth'] > 0.009, df_count['delta_depth'] < 0.011),df_count["delta_depth"] / df_count["duration"],0)

li2=df_count.values.tolist()
li_depth = df_count['depth'].tolist()
li_delta = df_count['delta_depth'].tolist()
li_duration = df_count['duration'].tolist()
li_inter = df_count['inter_depth'].tolist()


#empty List of Lists with the number of elements of the sublist corresponding to the duration
out=[]
for number in li_duration:
  out.append(li_inter[:number])  

#Pass values from interpolated depth to the respective sublists --> Liste 1
out = [[i]*j for i, j in zip(li_inter, [len(j) for j in out])] 

#Transfer elements from delta_depth to sublists --> Liste 2
def extractDigits(lst):
    return list(map(lambda el:[el], lst))            
lst=extractDigits(li_delta)

#Merge list 1 and list 2
list1 = out
list2 = lst
new_list = []
for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=[]):
    new_list.append([y if y else x for x, y in zip_longest(l1, l2)])
new_list
```

After merging the [first elements of the sublists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIdu4.png) the original depth values are followed by the interpolated values. But the sublists should contain only interpolated values.

Now I have the following questions:

1. is there in general a better approach to this problem?
2. How could I solve the problem with merging, or...
3. ... find a way to override the wrong first elements in the sublists

[The desired result would look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISch9.png).

Any help would be much appreciated, as I'm very unexperienced in python and totally stuck.

Comment: Could you provide a picture or file of your desired result? That always makes things easier to understand.

Comment: updated the question with an [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0MWqVazAnA3vXFQAGceIYfbyxazoaiU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104745763327967732762&rtpof=true&sd=true) to an example file and the desired result [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISch9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure someone could write something prettier, but I think this will work just fine:

Edited to some kinda messy scripting. I think this will do what you need it to though

```
_list_helper1 = df["Depth [m]"].to_list()
_list_helper1.insert(0, 0)
_list_helper1.insert(0, 0)
_list_helper1 = _list_helper1[:-2]
df["helper1"] = _list_helper1

_list = df["Depth [m]"].to_list()  # grab all depth values
_list.insert(0, 0)  # insert a value at the beginning to offset from original col
_list = _list[0:-1]  # Delete the very last item

df["helper"] = _list  # add the list to a helper col which is now offset
df["delta depth"] = df["Depth [m]"] - df["helper"]  # subtract helper col from original


_id = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "Depth [m]"] == df.loc[i, "helper"]:
        break_val = df.loc[i, "Depth [m]"]
        break_val_2 = df.loc[i+1, "Depth [m]"]
        if break_val_2 == break_val:
            df.loc[i, "IDcol"] = _id
            df.loc[i+1, "IDcol"] = _id
        else:
            _id += 1


depth = df["IDcol"].to_list()
depth = list(dict.fromkeys(depth))
depth = [x for x in depth if str(x) != 'nan']

increments = []
for i in depth:
    _df = df.copy()
    _df = _df[_df["IDcol"] == i]
    _df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    div_by = len(_df)
    increment = _df.loc[0, "helper"] - _df.loc[0, "helper1"]
    _df["delta depth"] = increment / div_by
    _increment = increment / div_by
    base_value = _df.loc[0, "Depth [m]"]

    for y in range(div_by):
        _df.loc[y, "Depth [m]"] = base_value + ((y + 1) * _increment)

    increments.append(_df)

df["IDcol"] = df["IDcol"].fillna("KEEP")
df = df[df["IDcol"] == "KEEP"]
increments.append(df)
df = pd.concat(increments)
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df[["index", "Depth [m]", "delta depth", "IDcol"]]  # and whatever other cols u want
```

Comment: I think your code does the same like this:  
`df_count["delta_depth"] = df_count["depth"].diff()`  
`df_count=df_count.fillna(0)`  

Afterwards I was counting the amount of same depth values to iterate the depth  
`df_count["inter_depth"] = np.where(np.logical_and(df_count['delta_depth'] > 0.009, df_count['delta_depth'] < 0.011),df_count["delta_depth"] / df_count["duration"],0)`

Comment: thank you so much for your effort! I've tested it with the example data file but it doesn't work properly caused by `increment = _df.loc[0, "helper"] - _df.loc[0, "helper1"]`
as "helper1" seems not to exist.
I'm a little confused by `increments`, `increment` and `_increment`.
`div_by` is the Number of consecutive depths, rigth?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I omitted the first part of the code (added now, try it again).
So basically, increments is a list to hold all values where the increment is calculated and not given (your original issue), _increment is is the flat increment where the spacing is evenly divided by number of values before a whole increment is made and increment is the entire increment that needs to be divided (turns into _increments).
I hope that is an okay explanation!

Comment: thanks again for your great help! I've added `df1 = df1.merge(df[['Depth [m]', 'index']],on='index',how="left")` to your code as all indexes that where not iterated are not contained in the dataset. The [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FxdncTHJDkKsRZoTHX6RSwGI9UhntUIm/view?usp=sharing) looks good although there are areas, where the iteration [didn't work properly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OeAXptYct9_ckERDK2TNeyvSvCxYRVeQ/view?usp=sharing). But these areas are not of interest for further calculations.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

A good idea is to try and understand my code and improve it yourself. That'll allow you to maintain it as well as maybe get those last bits.

You can feel free to shoot me a message if something is unclear.